# Web parts continuously loading

Tags: web-part, custom-masterpage, custom, homepage

Our organization is running a Microsoft hosted SharePoint 2013 Cloud Service as our intranet. It was originally set up by a consultant, who built two "custom" web parts for the site. One is a calendar display and one is a quicklinks/search bar.

These two web parts will no longer load properly (just show a spinning wheel) on the main/home page. They do seem to work on other pages within the site.

No permission settings were changed, and these parts are embedded in the master site pages. Other browsers have been tried along with those outside of the organization (to eliminate any firewall issues).

Any suggestions for troubleshooting this issue?

*Disclaimer: I am not a SharePoint expert, please be kind

[image]

Comment: In addition to Josh's answer, I would say to check to see if the webparts use Javascript and are experiencing Javascript errors.  You can do this by opening the developer tools in any browser (most I think open by hitting F12).  Look around in the dev tools until you find a tab or window section called "Console".  Once you have located the Console, refresh the browser and look for errors reported in the console.

Comment: regarding the Console, I had previously looked at that and there are some errors listed - I'm just not sure what to do with that information (see screenshot). I initially thought it was a firewall issue - but it's replicating on PCs outside the org. Is there any other way to view error logs? [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3unl.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3unl.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Without an error message, this is really hard to troubleshoot.  I would start by looking at the search service application and search schema since these webparts seem to be search driven.